# Checking string type

Tags: typescript

I've tried to get this json file into my code.

```
  "item1": {
    "key": "test1",
    "displayName": "test1",
    "max": "-",
    "min": 0
  },
  "item2": {
    "key": "test2",
    "displayName": "test2",
    "max": 15,
    "min": 0
  },
  ...
```

Here is the point.

The json file has max field and it has two types string | number.

So when I try to get field of max it occurs type error even I check the type string in my code.

```
  const rules = Object.values(jsonFile); // key, displayName, max, min

  //...

  const validateEachIndex = (value: number, index: number): [boolean, string] => {
    if (typeof rules[index].max === "string") {
      createErrorCode(
        new NumberValidator(value)
          .min(rules[index].min)
          .end()
      );      
    } else {
    createErrorCode(
      new NumberValidator(value)
        .max(rules[index].max)  // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2345)
        .min(rules[index].min)
        .end()
    );
    }
  };
```

NumberValidator:

```
class NumberValidator {
  private target: number;
  private errorCode: number;
  constructor(target: number) {
    this.target = target;
    this.errorCode = ErrorCodes.SUCCESS;
  }

  max(max: number) {
    if (this.target > max) {
      this.errorCode = ErrorCodes.MAX;
    }

    return this;
  }

  min(min: number) {
    if (this.target < min) {
      this.errorCode = ErrorCodes.MIN;
    }

    return this;
  }

  end() {
    return this.errorCode;
  }
}
```

In this case how to avoid type error?

Please let me know if you need more info thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const validateEachIndex = (value: number, index: number): [boolean, string] => {
if (typeof rules[index].max === "string") {
  createErrorCode(
    new NumberValidator(value)
      .min(rules[index].min)
      .end()
  );      
} else {
createErrorCode(
  new NumberValidator(value)
    .max(Number(rules[index].max))  // Convert to number
    .min(rules[index].min)
    .end()
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast your string to a number if you are sure it is a number

```
createErrorCode(
      new NumberValidator(value)
        .max(Number(rules[index].max))  // OK !
        .min(rules[index].min)
        .end()
    );
```